# Postfix behind a relay to handle incoming and outgoing mail with /etc/aliases

Tags: linux, debian, postfix, exchange, email-server

I'm trying to setup `postfix` on a Linux machine (Debian 8 with Postfix 2.11). But I have some troubles getting `/etc/aliases` to work correctly.

The setup is as follows: A MS Exchange server is the actual mail server - it recieves mails and sends mails, and it is in the same local network as the Linux machine. Postfix on the Linux machine does use this Exchange machine as a relayhost to send mails. This works, so for example `mail external@gmail.com` arrives.

Now on the Exchange there exists a mail address that is forwarded to the Linux machine. In `/etc/aliases` I have an alias for this that is a pipe to a program, because the mails going to this address contain some code that should be parsed by the program.

In order to make this work, I have to alter the `mydestination` setting in `main.cf`. But as soon as I do so, Postfix stops relaying mails when their alias of `/etc/aliases` is used. Only typing the long name works. This is my configuration (I started from zero):

```
# main.cf
# our internet domain name (the thing after the "@")
mydomain = example.com

# this is the critical setting
mydestination = linuxmachine, 192.168.1.200, $mydomain

# IP of Exchange
relayhost = 192.168.1.100

# so that addresses look correct
masquerade_domains = $mydomain

# in order to make the pipe programm work with correct permission
default_privs = myuser
```

With this configuration the piping of incoming mail works, but sending mail to an alias does not work:

```
# /etc/alias
# none of the entries are actual users on the linux machine!

#works when mail to parser@example.com comes from external through Exchange to Linux
parser: |/home/user/programname 

# command "mail external" does not work! It sends to external@linuxmachine"
external: externalmail@gmail.com
```

If I comment out the line `mydestination` in `main.cf` then `mail external` sends a mail to `externalmail@gmail.com` (which arrives), but incoming mail to `parser@example.com` is not send through the pipe. So, just the other way round.

What do I have to enter in `main.cf` or `/etc/aliases` to be able to send mails from my Linux machine using short names and at the same time be able to receive mail to a pipe? All I want is that a special address is parsed on the linux machine and that linux users are able to send mails to selected addresses using short names as a "luxory" (instead of having to type full email addresses).

Update:
`postconf -n` output:

```
config_directory = /etc/postfix
default_privs = myuser
masquerade_domains = $mydomain
mydestination = linuxmachine, 192.168.1.200, $mydomain
mydomain = example.com
relayhost = 192.168.1.100
```

Update 2: Output from `/var/log/mail.info` when doing `mail external` (mail to alias) with `mydestination` set like above:

```
Jun 19 10:45:27 linuxmachine postfix/smtp[26425]: 6DFE02003AD: to=<external@linuxmachine.example.com>, orig_to=<external>, relay=192.168.1.100[192.168.1.100]:25, delay=0.24, delays=0/0/0/0.24, dsn=2.6.0, status=sent (250 2.6.0 <20150619084527.6DFE02003AD@linuxmachine.example.com> [InternalId=162319] Queued mail for delivery)
```

Update 3, after changing `mydestination` according to the proposed answer, the `mail.info` log shows the following line when doing `mail external`:

```
Jun 19 16:07:31 linuxmachine postfix/smtp[2299]: B562720039C: to=<externalmail@gmail.com>, orig_to=<external>, relay=192.168.1.100[192.168.1.100]:25, delay=2.6, delays=0/0/0/2.5, dsn=2.6.0, status=sent (250 2.6.0 <20150619140728.B359620039E@linuxmachine.example.com> [InternalId=162971] Queued mail for delivery)
```

Comment: Can you post the output of `postconf -n`? Also, can you provide maillog when postfix fail to send to external@gmail.com?

Comment: @masegaloeh I added `postconf -n` (with `mydestination` set). Will add  log later.

Comment: @masegaloeh Added the log

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The obvious solution is put `$myhostname` or linuxmachine.example.com in `mydestination` parameter.

### explanation

Before the config modification, here the background event after you send email via `mail external`

- Postfix receives email via pickup service.
- Because the recipient doesn't have domain parts and (by default) parameter [`append_at_myorigin`](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#append_at_myorigin) has value `yes`, then postfix will rewrite recipient address to external@linuxmachine.example.com (you can see it in mail.log above)
- By default, parameter [`mydestination`](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#mydestination) has value `$myhostname` or linuxmachine.example.com, so postfix apply aliasing map in `/etc/aliases`.
- Postfix aliased external@linuxmachine.example.com to external@gmail.com and then send it to gmail host

Now after config modification, this is what happens

- Postfix receives email via pickup service.
- Because the recipient doesn't have domain parts and (by default) parameter [`append_at_myorigin`](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#append_at_myorigin) has value `yes`, then postfix will rewrite recipient address to external@linuxmachine.example.com (you can see it in mail.log above)
- Now `mydestination` doesn't contain `$myhostname` or linuxmachine.example.com, so postfix won't apply aliasing in `/etc/aliases`

Comment: I now see `to=<external@gmail.com>, orig_to=<external>` in `mail.info`, but the mail still does not arrive in the external inbox, however. I tested it with several external mail addresses from different e-mail providers (I run `newaliases` each time, of course).

Comment: When I post a mail to `me@example.com` via alias `internal: me@example.com` the mail correctly arrives in the Exchange inbox. But If I then look at the mail header, it has: `To: <internal@example.com` instead of `me@example.com`. I assume this is the problem why it does not arrive at external servers (Envelope and Mail Headers differ). How do I change this?

Comment: Can you update the question with log after you modified mydestination?

Comment: Updated the question with the `mail.info` message after changing `mydestination` and doing `mail external`.

Comment: Well, mail.log said that postfix successfully relay email to exchange. Please also checks exchange log.